# How to Change Gitlab Ci Runner Docker Container Names

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I register gitlab runners to gitlab ci in order to trig docker containers.

Everything OK.No problem about run-time.

But i have problem about the name of docker containers. Gitlab runner gives name to the containers such as "runner-408afb1d-project-3-concurrent-0-build".

In the first part of this generated name is consisting of the first 8 digits of the runner token.

I try to give fix and custom name for that containers created by gitlab runner. But i could not find sufficient info. Is there anyone experienced such kind of issue ?

Comment: What is your exact question; How to change the container name of your runner? Then my question would be; why do you want to know that? Your runner executes your jobs. If you use containers in your jobs there is a way to determine the name. So please provide your exact need.

Comment: I would like to use it as host resolver. For the mysql test image.